# Spring boot ignores main class

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have a project (spring boot, maven, war) and I need to split it into two projects. New project depends on classes from the first project, so the new project has dependency to the first one. Unfortunately, both projects have main class and the new project always runs main class from the first project when it's deployed to tomcat. I have defined start class and main class in my pom.xml and I can see, that generated war file contains manifest with correct main class, but it doesn't help... What I'm doing wrong?

My pom.xml from new project (important parts):

```
<project ...
    <properties>
        <start-class>x.y.z.a.NewApplication</start-class>
    </properties>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
            <artifactId>OriginalProject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <classifier>classes</classifier>
        </dependency>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>x.y.z.a.NewApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>x.y.z.a.NewApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
...
```

Manifest from war file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: michal
Start-Class: x.y.z.a.NewApplication
Spring-Boot-Version: 1.2.1.RELEASE
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.0.5
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_25
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher
```

Application runs on Apache Tomcat 8.0.12.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not related to spring boot, but to maven-war-plugin. The application runs correctly on my local computer with spring boot and its embedded tomcat, but it cannot run when it is deployed on standalone tomcat server.

Comment: Or this could be related to wicket - there are two WebApplication classes and on standalone tomcat is the bad one runned ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found my mistake - I have to override SpringBootServletInitializer class from first project to point to the correct main class. So I've added new implementation of SpringBootServletInitializer class in the new project. The correct implementation is initialized using spring @Profile annotation.

Comment: Can you please add an example snippet about what you did?